# Xamarin Forms ListView with more than one datatemplate

Tags: listview, cell, datatemplate, xamarin.forms

In XamarinForms I have to develop a page which is displaying UserSettings. Therefore I created a SettingsPage which inherits from ContentPage. On this page I have a ListView which ItemSource is an ObservableCollection.
All cells on this page must have an Label on the left side with an Entry underneath it. The right side of this Cell must display an Image or SwitchControl. That depends on the UserSetting it is displaying.

So far I created a SettingsPage and a custom Cell for the ItemTemplate of the ListView. In this code the needed Image is hardcoded, that also has to change in the future.
What is the best way to achieve this? I am totally new to XamarinForms, so hints on the code so far are appreciated.

Thanks,
HJS

```html
public class SettingsPage : ContentPage
{
        public SettingsPage ()
        {
                var userSettings = DemoData.UserSettings ();
                var listView = new ListView { ItemsSource = userSettings };
                listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(UserCell));
                listView.RowHeight = 60;

                Content = listView;
        }
}
```

```html
public class UserCell : ViewCell
{
        public UserCell ()
        {
                var titleLabel = new Label ();
                var titleBinding = new Binding ("Name");
                titleLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, titleBinding);

                var valueEntry = new Entry ();
                var valueBinding = new Binding ("Value");
                valueEntry.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, valueBinding);

                var accessoryImage = new Image ();
                accessoryImage.Source = "ic_action_new.png";

                var stackLayout = new StackLayout ();
                stackLayout.Children.Add (titleLabel);
                stackLayout.Children.Add (valueEntry);

                var grid = new Grid {

                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

                        ColumnDefinitions = {
                                new ColumnDefinition{ Width = 200 },
                                new ColumnDefinition{ Width = 50 }
                        }
                };

                grid.Children.Add (stackLayout, 0, 0);
                Grid.SetColumnSpan (stackLayout, 1);
                grid.Children.Add (accessoryImage, 1, 0);

                View = grid;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So actually I see two questions in there:

- How to change the hardcoded picture
- How to show either `SwitchControl` or `Image`

Both are answered by: Use data binding!

Just as you have created a binding for the property `Text` of `Label` an the property `Text` of `Entry` you can also create a binding for the property `Source` of `Image`. The type of the property in your view model would be of type `string` just as you assigned a string with the image's source hard-coded in your `ViewCell`.

And to either show a `SwitchControl` or an `Image`, you can also bind the property `IsVisible` which both `Image` and `SwitchControl` inherit from `VisualElement`. So you would basically instantiate both an `Image` and a `SwitchControl` and add them to your layout in `ViewCell` and bind their respective `IsVisible` property to two different boolean properties of your view model. This allows you to implement the logic to decide when one is shown or another in your view model, just the way it should be in MVVM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With some help from the internet I wrote a DataTemplateSelector for the ListView. But I will try out your suggestion.